# GCM sent but not received always

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

We have developed an app (Android and iOS) which uses gcm to send push notifications.
Everything works fine but, if me or any user is a couple of days without opening the app, push notifications don't work.
I have tested with my current token once I know it is not working, and when I send the downstream message to gcm, the service responses me "success": 1,
but message is not been delivered to my device.

It is not clear in the docs, but do I need a service on my apps on which periodically I must call

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

to be always "up and ready" ???

Same thing is happening with iOS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) may help you.
As documentation; delay_while_idle and time_to_live parameters may solve your problem. Remember GCM server hold messages maximum 4 weeks and time_to_live take value as seconds. We are using GCM both ios and android and all messages deliver to devices. Sometimes ios gets notification with some delay

Comment: iOS is working fine. The problem is in Android systems. We have detected when the user does not run the app (and does not request for a token and a registration) in three or 4 days, google server responses success 1 but message is not delivered. We continue doing test.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I will also check this scenario

Comment: I have tested with an app which have not been running since Friday and the notification delivered to the device.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found what was happening.
Samnsung is installing an app called SmartManager on their android devices.
This app "kills" GCM sockets when the app is "optimized" (unused for 3 days).

What we did? We detected the SmartManager package and we warned the user  of this behaviour.
Also we did exponencial backoff at the time of obtain the gcm token.